# Finding $\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\tan(x)-1}{x-\pi/4}$.

Tags: limits

find the limit $$\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\tan(x)-1}{x-\pi/4}$$

direct substitution results in $0/0$

and it seems that there's no way to factor it

When I look at its graph

It's clear that it has the limit ***2*** as $x$ approaches $\pi/4$

the question is ***How to factor this function*** ??
!

Comment: how about L'Hôpital?

Comment: Do the substitution $x\leadsto x-\pi/4=n$, you'll get: $$\lim_{n\to0}\dfrac{\tan(n+\pi/4)-1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 4):

**Without** applying L'Hospital's Rule,
$$\eqalign{
  & \tan (x - {\pi  \over 4}) = {{\tan x - 1} \over {1 + \tan x}} \longrightarrow \tan x - 1 = (1 + \tan x)\tan (x - {\pi  \over 4})  \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {\pi  \over 4}} {{\tan x - 1} \over {x - {\pi  \over 4}}}  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {\pi  \over 4}} {{(1 + \tan x)\tan (x - {\pi  \over 4})} \over {x - {\pi  \over 4}}}  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {\pi  \over 4}} {{(1 + \tan x)(x - {\pi  \over 4})} \over {x - {\pi  \over 4}}}  \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {\pi  \over 4}} (1 + \tan x)  \cr 
  &  = 2 \cr} $$

Comment: At the end of the day the problem comes down to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan(x)}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @Ian Of course. The most common approach is equivalent infinitesimal replacement when solving the limits.

Answer (score 3):

Use L'Hopital's rule.
$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan{x}-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1+\tan^2(x)}{1}=2$

Comment: Isn't applying L'Hôpital here circular reasoning?

Comment: No, L'Hopital is used in these situations. Why do you say it is circlular reasoning?

Comment: I'm not sure it applies here, but it seems a bit "dangerous" to use it for [trigonometric expressions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13011/83553).

Comment: If you do not want to use L'Hopital, then you can write the Talor expansion of the nominator and use just two terms: $\tan(x)=1+2(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$, then you see that the limit is equal to $2$. However L'Hopital is applicable here

Comment: this is the first time i hear about L'Hopital's rule ! is there another way of solving it?

Comment: I wrote another solution in the previous comment, by using Taylor's expansion

Answer (score 3):

By using Taylor's expansion we have $\tan(x)\simeq 1+2(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$, around $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, hence we can say:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan(x)-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1+2(x-\frac{\pi}{4})-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=2$

Comment: I know nothing about Taylor's expansion :( . no other ways of solving this problem other than Taylor's expansion or  L'Hopital's rule..?

Comment: No, I think you should practice more to become familiar with these basic concepts of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$ this can be thinked as difference quotient. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan\left(x\right)-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$ is just like $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)}{x-x_0}$ where $f(x)$ is $\tan(x)$ and $x_0$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Now, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan\left(x\right)-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=f'(x)$. $f'(x)=D(\tan x)=1+\tan^2x$. And then
$f'(\frac{\pi}{4})=1+\tan^2(\frac{\pi}{4})=1+1^2=2$

Answer (score 1):

With a shift of the variable ($t\to0$),

$$\frac{\tan(t+\frac\pi4)-1}{t}=\frac{\dfrac{1+\tan t}{1-\tan t}-1}t=\frac{2\tan t}{t(1-\tan t)}\to2.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to factor! This limit is not so coincidentally the derivative of $f(x)=\tan(x)$ at the point $x=\pi/4$. By a substitution it can be shown $$ f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a }\frac{f(x) - f(a) }{x-a} $$

Specifically $$ \tan'(\pi/4) =\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}$$ Then using the fact that $ \tan (x) ' =\sec^2( x)  $ we immediately get the limit is $$ \sec\left(\pi/4\right)^2 = \left(\frac {2}{\sqrt 2 } \right)^2 = 2 $$